# Change the keyboard at the password unlock screen

Tags: keyboard, lock-screens

I have a Samsung Galaxy 4.2 player.  I've gotten this to replace my old IPod Touch.  I've been happy with it, but I'm having a problem with the unlock screen.

I've set my unlock screen to use a password.  But my issue with the Samsung keyboard is that it doesn't "pop-out" the letters as I type them.  Instead, it simply lights the key in a subtle way - too subtle for me to notice when I accidentally tap the character beside the one I intended to.  As a result, I mistype the password frequently, which is pretty annoying.

The [Gingerbread](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moo.android.inputmethod.latin.free&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5tb28uYW5kcm9pZC5pbnB1dG1ldGhvZC5sYXRpbi5mcmVlIl0.) keyboard I have does pop out the characters as I type.  I've been happy with it, but I can't seem to find a way to use that keyboard as my keyboard to unlock the device.

So my question is: is there a way for me to change the keyboard at the unlock screen?

Thanks!

Comment: What os version are you on? 2.3?

Comment: Correct - 2.3.6.